# What is circuit mapping?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In ODEs we have been studying circuit mappings, I am having a hard time understanding them, and cant seem to find any resources on them, I guess it goes by a different name usually.

Circuit mappings map the solution space $V[0,R]$ on the positive real line to itself by extending it to complex space then restricting to negative part of the real line, extending to complex space and then restricting back to positive real line.
It is part of singular points chapter in ODEs book, and the name composite mapping is also mentioned.

Do you know any resources on circuit mappings

Example of circuit mapping:
Let $\lambda_1$ $\lambda_2$ be the roots of the indicial equation from an Euler equation, then $z^{\lambda_1}$, $z^{\lambda_2}$ form a basis of solutions for the Euler eq. There is a basis $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ for the corresponding system of the Euler eq., $u(z) = (z^{\lambda_1}, \lambda_1*z^{\lambda_1-1}$). u is defined only on the positive real axis, continuing it one revolution around the axis: $z^{\lambda_1}=e^{\lambda_1ln(z)}$ continuing it to $e^{\lambda_1(ln(z)+2\pi i)}$, thus mapping S:$Su(z) = e^{2\pi ie^\lambda_1} u(z)$ similarly for v(z), then S is a diagonal matrix with $e^{2\pi ie^\lambda_1}, e^{2\pi ie^\lambda_2}$ on the diagonals.

Comment: You have not given any actual example of circuit mapping. We have no idea what it is from your unspecific description.

Comment: @somos I added an example which was in my book